# How to align rows of text vertically outside of table environment?

Tags: align, vertical-alignment

I have many rows of text that need to be aligned with one another, similarly to Blast text output:

```
Query  1    MASETPRVDPTEISNVNAPVFRIIAQIKSQPTESQLILQSPTISSKNGSEVEMITLNNIR  60
            MASETPR+DPTEISN+NAPVFRI+AQIKSQPTESQL+LQSPTISSKN  E+EMITLNNIR
Sbjct  1    MASETPRIDPTEISNINAPVFRIVAQIKSQPTESQLVLQSPTISSKNSGEIEMITLNNIR  60
```

and I'm trying to output text like that in LaTeX.

I have gotten close, but the problem is that the spacing on the left hand side is difficult to reproduce within LaTeX.

I have tried a table, but the spaces are unacceptably large.

This is the closest that I've come to solving the problem, but the vertical alignment looks really bad:

```
\begin{mymonoframe} \tiny
Query   RFDRLVAGQIPT----GWNAKTYGISDDIISQVDPITLFVLVSVVEAFIASGITDPYEMYKYVHVSEVGNCSGSGMGG-------VSALRGMFKDRFKDE    100\\
midline ++   +AG+I +    GW      ++  +  ++D   L+++ +  +A    GIT+  E+   +  S  G   GS MGG       + ALR  +K      \\
hit     KYPTRIAGEIKSFSTDGW------VAPKLAKRMDKFMLYLITAGKKALENGGITE--EVMNELDKSRCGVLVGSAMGGMKIFSDAIEALRVSYKK-----\\

Query   PVQNDILQESFINTMSAWVNMLLISSSGPIKTPVGACATSVESVDIGVETILSGKARICIVGGYD-DFQEEGSFEFGNMKATSNTLEEFEHGRTPAEMSR    200\\
midline    N          M + +  + +   GP  +   ACATS   +      I  G+  + + GG D      G   F   +A S      +    PA+ SR\\
hit     --MNPFCVPFATTNMGSAILAMDLGWMGPNYSISTACATSNFCILNAANHIRRGETDVMLCGGSDAPIIPIGLGGFVACRALS------QRNNDPAKASR\\

Query   PATTTRNGFMEAQGAGIQIIMQADLALKMGVPIYGIVAMAATATDKIGRSVPAP-GKGILTTAREHHSSVKYASPNLN  278\\
midline P    R+GF+  +GAG+ ++ + + A + G  IY      +   D    + P P G+G++       +    A  ++N\\
hit     PWDVDRDGFVMGEGAGVLLLEELEHAKQRGAQIYAEFLGGSFTCDAYHMTEPHPEGRGVILCIENALADAGVAKEDIN\\

\end{mymonoframe}
```

I've tried monospace fonts and all that, but the spacing just isn't working.

[Align Text vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271011/align-text-vertically) looks similar, but he/she is doing something different.

How can I reproduce text like the Blast in LaTeX?

Comment: Unfortunately none of your posted code does compile in my place. Can you please add the missing parts to make it compile AND still demonstrate your problem? Thank you

Comment: In particular, do let us know how or where the `mymonoframe` environment is defined.

Comment: the input form is not very clear but if it's all monospace fonts already line broken don't you just want `\begin{verbatim}....\end{verbatim}` ?  Describing the desired form as "like blast output" will not help most people including me, who have no idea what that looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want a simple `verbatim`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

{\fontsize{5.5pt}{7pt}\selectfont %bigger than \tiny, smaller than \scriptsize
\begin{verbatim}
Query   RFDRLVAGQIPT----GWNAKTYGISDDIISQVDPITLFVLVSVVEAFIASGITDPYEMYKYVHVSEVGNCSGSGMGG-------VSALRGMFKDRFKDE    100
midline ++   +AG+I +    GW      ++  +  ++D   L+++ +  +A    GIT+  E+   +  S  G   GS MGG       + ALR  +K      
hit     KYPTRIAGEIKSFSTDGW------VAPKLAKRMDKFMLYLITAGKKALENGGITE--EVMNELDKSRCGVLVGSAMGGMKIFSDAIEALRVSYKK-----

Query   PVQNDILQESFINTMSAWVNMLLISSSGPIKTPVGACATSVESVDIGVETILSGKARICIVGGYD-DFQEEGSFEFGNMKATSNTLEEFEHGRTPAEMSR    200
midline    N          M + +  + +   GP  +   ACATS   +      I  G+  + + GG D      G   F   +A S      +    PA+ SR
hit     --MNPFCVPFATTNMGSAILAMDLGWMGPNYSISTACATSNFCILNAANHIRRGETDVMLCGGSDAPIIPIGLGGFVACRALS------QRNNDPAKASR

Query   PATTTRNGFMEAQGAGIQIIMQADLALKMGVPIYGIVAMAATATDKIGRSVPAP-GKGILTTAREHHSSVKYASPNLN  278
midline P    R+GF+  +GAG+ ++ + + A + G  IY      +   D    + P P G+G++       +    A  ++N
hit     PWDVDRDGFVMGEGAGVLLLEELEHAKQRGAQIYAEFLGGSFTCDAYHMTEPHPEGRGVILCIENALADAGVAKEDIN
\end{verbatim}
}

\end{document}
```